# Why do I get a SQLITE_MISUSE : Out of Memory error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am writing an *iOS* application that directly accesses `SQLite`. I have done this sort of thing many times on *Android*, so I'm struggling to see where my error lies - however my inserts are returning the `SQLITE_MISUSE` error (code 21), with the message "out of Memory". Below are the steps I have taken to lead me to this insert.

First, the **table creation**:

```
NSString *sql = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UsersTable (lastName TEXT,id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,picture BLOB,firstName TEXT,age TEXT,email TEXT,sex TEXT,height TEXT,weight TEXT)";

//create the database if it does not yet exist
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: path ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [path UTF8String];

    //This was if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &store) == SQLITE_OK) , but it has not made a difference.
    if (sqlite3_open_v2(dbpath, &store, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg = NULL;
        const char *sql_stmt = [sql UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_exec(store, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create table: %s", errMsg);
        }
        if (errMsg)
            sqlite3_free(errMsg);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
    }
}
```

Next, the **insert** (currently using the email address for the user ID):

```
INSERT INTO UsersTable (id,lastName,firstName,email) VALUES ("jsmith@foobar.com","Smith","John","jsmith@foobar.com")
```

I am using one selector for all database interactions, so the above text is passed here:

```
-(int)execSQL:(NSString *)statement
{
    NSLog(@"%@",statement);

    const char *insert_stmt = [statement UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *stmnt;

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(store, insert_stmt, -1, &stmnt, NULL);
    int result = sqlite3_step(stmnt);

    sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);

    if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(store));//This prints "Error: out of memory"
    }
    return result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Get the full error. `NSLog(@"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(store));`.

Comment: sqlite expects text values to be in single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: One last thing - just in case - do not use string formats to create your SQL statements. Prepare the statement then use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` to bind the value into the query. `INSERT INTO table (c1, c2, c2) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`. The calls to `sqlite3_bind_xxx` will replace the `?` with the proper value. This ensures values are properly quoted and special characters are properly escaped.

Comment: The "out of memory" error almost always means that your database pointer (your `sqlite3 *` variable) has not been set properly with a call to `sqlite3_open_v2`.

Comment: @rmaddy I added the code I use to open the database, and changed from using `sqlite3_open` to `sqlite3_open_v2`, but am still getting the same error. Any other pointers? (I'm currently working on your other suggestions)

Comment: Have you verified that the database is actually being opened properly and by the time you call the code to do the insert, your `store` variable is still properly setup from the open database? Also, initialize `store` to `NULL` just prior to calling `sqlite3_open` and again after calling `sqlite3_close`.

Comment: @rmaddy, I set `store` to `NULL` before my open, but it does not help. I also don't call `sqlite3_close` until my object is deallocated by the garbage collector. Does this need to be called after every sql statement?

Comment: See Rob's answer. You are not opening the database if the file already exists. You should call `sqlite3_open_v2` whether it exists or not. You just want to create the tables if it didn't yet exist.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your open routine is only creating/opening the database if the database doesn't exist. Your database probably already exists and thus your routine isn't even opening it.

Bottom line, if you try calling SQLite functions without opening the database, you will get the `SQLITE_MISUSE` return code (which indicates that the SQLite functions were not called in the right order) and the `sqlite3_errmsg` will return the cryptic "out of memory" error.

---

A couple of other, unrelated observations:

1. You really should check the return code of `sqlite3_prepare` as well:

   ```
   - (int)execSQL:(NSString *)statement
   {
       int result;

       NSLog(@"%@",statement);

       const char *insert_stmt = [statement UTF8String];
       sqlite3_stmt *stmnt;

       if ((result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(store, insert_stmt, -1, &stmnt, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK)
       {
           NSLog(@"%s: prepare failure '%s' (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(store), result);
           return result;
       }

       if ((result = sqlite3_step(stmnt)) != SQLITE_DONE)
       {
           NSLog(@"%s: step failure: '%s' (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(store), result);
       }

       sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);

       return result;
   }
   ```

   In my experience, many common development problems are related to the SQL itself, something that is identified by checking the return code of the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` statement.
2. You really should not be building your SQL statement in a `NSString`. You open yourself to SQL injection attacks or, considering the more benign situation, just a SQL errors if someone's name has a quotation mark in it, e.g. `The "Destroyer"`. You should be using `?` placeholders and then use [`sqlite3_bind_xxx`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) functions to bind the values. Something like:

   ```
   - (int)insertIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
                  lastName:(NSString *)lastName
                 firstName:(NSString *)firstName
                     email:(NSString *)email
   {
       int result;

       const char *insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO UsersTable (id, lastName, firstName, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
       sqlite3_stmt *stmnt;

       if ((result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(store, insert_stmt, -1, &stmnt, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK)
       {
           NSLog(@"%s: prepare failure '%s' (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(store), result);
           return result;
       }

       if ((result = sqlite3_bind_text(stmnt, 1, [identifier UTF8String], -1, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK)
       {
           NSLog(@"%s: bind #1 failure '%s' (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(store), result);
           sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);
           return result;
       }

       if ((result = sqlite3_bind_text(stmnt, 2, [lastName UTF8String], -1, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK)
       {
           NSLog(@"%s: bind #2 failure '%s' (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(store), result);
           sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);
           return result;
       }

       if ((result = sqlite3_bind_text(stmnt, 3, [firstName UTF8String], -1, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK)
       {
           NSLog(@"%s: bind #3 failure '%s' (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(store), result);
           sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);
           return result;
       }

       if ((result = sqlite3_bind_text(stmnt, 4, [email UTF8String], -1, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK)
       {
           NSLog(@"%s: bind #4 failure '%s' (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(store), result);
           sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);
           return result;
       }

       if ((result = sqlite3_step(stmnt)) != SQLITE_DONE)
       {
           NSLog(@"%s: step failure: '%s'", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(store));
       }

       sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);

       return result;
   }
   ```

   You can then call this like so:

   ```
   [self insertIdentifier:@"jsmith@foobar.com"
                 lastName:@"Smith"
                firstName:@"John"
                    email:@"jsmith@foobar.com"];
   ```
3. As you can see, as you start writing code where you're appropriately checking each and every return value, binding each variable, etc., your SQLite code gets hairy awfully quickly. I'd suggest you contemplate looking at [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). It's a nice, thin wrapper around the SQLite functions, which greatly simplifies the exercise of writing SQLite code in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the value of the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` statement.  If it's not `SQLITE_OK` then there's an issue.

Also, does the database file already exist?  If not, you need to create it or load it from the bundle.