# How to resolve sqlite error in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have created table in existing sqlite database in my application using following code :

```
-(NSString *)databasefilepath
{
    NSArray *path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentdirectorypath=[path objectAtIndex:0];
   //NSLog(@"file pateh  %@",documentdirectorypath);

    return [documentdirectorypath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ABC.sqlite"];

}
-(void)createTableRuntime
{
    //[self databasefilepath];


    sqlite3 *database;
    if (sqlite3_open([[self databasefilepath] UTF8String], &database)
        != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);

    }
    NSString *TlrmcreateSQL = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TLRMMatter(_id integer primary key autoincrement, CaseInfoID TEXT, ClientName TEXT, MatterName TEXT,FileName TEXT);";
    char *tlrmerrorMsg;
    if (sqlite3_exec (datbase, [TlrmcreateSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &tlrmerrorMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSLog(@"[ERR] : \t> CMD: %@ , Error: %s\n",TlrmcreateSQL , tlrmerrorMsg);
        sqlite3_close(datbase);

    }
    else
    {


    }


    NSString *create_sms_tablequery=@"CREATE TABLE TimesheetTask(_id integer primary key autoincrement,srno text,Taskid text,taskname text);";
    char *errormessage;
    if (sqlite3_exec(datbase, [create_sms_tablequery UTF8String], NULL,NULL, &errormessage)!=SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(datbase);
    }
    else
    {

    }

    NSString *create_event_tablequery=@"CREATE TABLE Expense(_id integer primary key autoincrement,ExpenseId text,ExpenseName text);";
    char *errormessageforeventtable;
    if (sqlite3_exec(datbase, [create_event_tablequery UTF8String], NULL,NULL, &errormessageforeventtable)!=SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(datbase);
    }
    else
    {

    };
}
```

But it does not create new table in my application database.
I don't know where is the error in my code.

Comment: Did you check error message, if any?

Comment: are you sure the database is open ?

Comment: @VinayKrishnan How to check error message?

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri yes

Comment: I would recommend to put a `NSLog` inside every `else` to realise which statement is actually failing.

Comment: sqlite3_errmsg(datbase)    error is out of memory

Comment: if you try calling SQLite functions without opening the database, you will get the SQLITE_MISUSE return code (which indicates that the SQLite functions were not called in the right order) and the sqlite3_errmsg will return the cryptic "out of memory" error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283117/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite-misuse-out-of-memory-error

Comment: I'd recommend using either Core Data or something like FMDB.   No one ever writes proper sqlite code the first time and there is little point in writing SQL by hand these days.